# Create rows dynamically on jsp using while loop

Tags: jsp, jdbc, dynamic, while-loop, html-table

I am trying to retrieve data from `hsqldb` and show it to the user in the form of a table. I am using while loop to see if there are more data to display, but jsp page is throwing compiler error on the line having while! please help.

Following is my jsp code is:

```
<%
Connection con = JDBCHelper.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps_sel = null;
HttpSession s = request.getSession(false);
ResultSet rs = null;
String username = (String)s.getAttribute("username");
String string = (String)request.getAttribute("string");
try {
    ps_sel = con.prepareStatement("select * from tasks where username = ? and (tname like ? or tasks like ?)");
    ps_sel.setString(1, username);
    ps_sel.setString(2, "%"+string+"%");
    ps_sel.setString(3, "%"+string+"%");
    ps_sel.execute();
    rs = ps_sel.getResultSet();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    rs = ps_sel.getResultSet();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        %>
            <tr>
                 <td><%= rs.getString(1)%></td> 
                 <td><%= rs.getString(2)%></td>
                 <td><%= rs.getString(3)%></td>
                 <td><%= rs.getString(4)%></td>
                 <td><%= rs.getString(5)%></td>
                 <td><%= rs.getString(6)%></td>                                   
            </tr>
        <% 
    }
%>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check with your java import statements and if no problem with imports then paste your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <% Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"); %>

    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>Fetching Data From a Database</TITLE>
        </HEAD>

        <BODY>
            <H1>Fetching Data From a Database</H1>
    <TABLE BORDER="1">
                <TR>
                   <TH>ID</TH>
                   <TH>Name</TH>
                   <TH>City</TH>
                   <TH>State</TH>
                   <TH>Country</TH>
               </TR>
            <% 
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(                                                       "Url", "YourName", "Password");

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    HttpSession s = request.getSession(false);
ResultSet rs = null;
String username = (String)s.getAttribute("username");
String string = (String)request.getAttribute("string");
 try {
    ps_sel = con.prepareStatement("select * from tasks where username = ? and (tname like ? or tasks like ?)");
    ps_sel.setString(1, username);
    ps_sel.setString(2, "%"+string+"%");
    ps_sel.setString(3, "%"+string+"%");
    ps_sel.execute();
    rs = ps_sel.getResultSet();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    rs = ps_sel.getResultSet();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        %>
               <TR>
                   <TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </TD>
                   <TD> <%= resultset.getString(2) %> </TD>
                   <TD> <%= resultset.getString(3) %> </TD>
                   <TD> <%= resultset.getString(4) %> </TD>
                   <TD> <%= resultset.getString(5) %> </TD>
               </TR>
                 <% 
               } 
           %>
</TABLE>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements in a jsp file is syntactically legal. But Avoid using them. Use POJOs to write java code. It is possible to use jstl for the same purpose. If you are a beginner, then using jstl here is the important learning here.